Sum of elements using slice of two columns
I need the sum of all elements in rows "faturamento" and "potFaturamento" that follows some criteria:
Same CNPJ
and same Year of "yearMonth" column:
The dataframe that I'm working on has 100M rows so performance is an important factor, I tried iterrows and it just can't handle so much data...
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["CNPJ", "faturamento", "potFaturamento", "yearMonth"])
df["CNPJ"] = ["01","01","01","02","02","02"]
df["faturamento"] = [100,300,150,200,150,100]
df["potFaturamento"] = [50,100,200,100,50,100]
df["yearMonth"] = ["202105","202406","202407","202206","202107","202207"]




CNPJ
faturamento
potFaturamento
yearMonth




01
100
50
202105


01
300
100
202406


01
150
200
202407


02
200
100
202206


02
150
50
202107


02
100
100
202207



now the output that I need:



CNPJ
sumFaturamento
sumPotFaturamento
year




01
100
50
2021


01
450
300
2024


02
300
200
2022


02
150
50
2021



I tried iterrows() with no success, I'm kinda new to this.

Using .groupby() and .sum().

df.assign(year=df.yearMonth.str[:4]).loc[:,['CNPJ', 'year', 'faturamento','potFaturamento']].groupby(['CNPJ', 'year'], as_index=False).sum()
